# Geodesic equations without solutions

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, geodesics

Is there a nontrivial Riemannian metric for which a geodesic equation doesn't have any solutions? What would such a metric mean physically?

Comment: No solutions anywhere, or no solutions at a particular point?

Comment: Differential equations have solutions even if they are not expressible in terms of functions that we have given names to.

Comment: @mmeent No solutions anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it does not exist. Given a Riemannian manifold with metric of class $C^2$, for every initial point and every initial vector, there is a unique maximal geodesic satisfying those initial conditions. That is a straightforward consequence of the existence and uniqueness theorem for integral curves on manifolds (here the tangent space manifold).

For the existence $C^1$ is enough, but it does not guarantee uniqueness. With less regularity it is not possible to write down the geodesic equation. (Actually one could require that the metric is differentiable but the derivatives are not continuous, in this case nor the existence is guaranteed. On the other hand such metric has continuous derivatives on a dense set.)

Comment: To what extent, if at all, do the set of all geodesics on a manifold determine the metric (assume any and all smoothness, etc.)? I mean we assign in every direction to every point a curve and declare it to be a geodesic (of course, same geodesic for any point on it), would this determine the metric?

Comment: The squared length of the geodesics completely determines the metric.

Comment: The point is that a geodesic admits a class of affine parameters. When you speak about the class of geodesics which affine parameter you consider?

Comment: I was not considering that at all for I thought the geodesic equation being independent of linear reparametrization $\lambda ' = a\lambda + b$ they should not matter. Is there a "natural" metric that might be independent of any "reasonable" nonlinear reparametrization of the geodesic curves even before we assign length to them? In other words, to what extent the points of the geodesic without assigning length to the curve determine the metric that is compatible with all the geodesics.

Comment: They cannot completely, think of $R^n$. Knowing only the geodesics up to reparametrization you cannot distinguish between the Euclidean metric and that metric rescaled with a constant factor. The same fact is true for every manifold.

Comment: Exactly. This is why I keep asking "to what extent"? I know that topology, i.e. here having the "bare" points of the curves, cannot determine the metric fully but must at least constrain it beyond that they satisfy the geodesic equation. Maybe it is a stupid question.